# Find gamma distribution parameters from empirical pdf (not from underlying data)

Tags: python, parameters, scipy, distribution

I'm trying to estimate the parameters of a gamma distribution that fits best the following arbitrary pdf.

[image: empirical distribution]

`scipy` work with MLE so `ss.gamma.fit` work with data such as histogram.

However, I don't have the underlying data since my distribution came from analytical calculus. (implied pdf from option chain with the Breeden-Litzenberger method, if that matters)

---

### What I've tried so far:

1. [Percentile method](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/56371/finding-probability-distribution-parameters-from-p) : I get `alpha` and `beta = 1/scale` but I cannot reconcile the `loc` parameter that `ss.gamma` need
2. with `scipy.optimize` : `least_squares, minimize, curve_fit` on both `ss.gamma.cdf` and `ss.gamma.pdf` to find parameters but I've `nan` or `inf` error from the solver (default parameters).
3. Percentile method to find initial guess, then minimise:

```py
    import scipy.stats as ss
    import numpy as np
        
    x = np.linspace(1000,5500)
    y = get_implied_pdf()
    
    y_cdf = np.cumsum(y)

    perc_20 = x[np.argmin(np.abs(y_cdf - .2))]
    perc_80 = x[np.argmin(np.abs(y_cdf - .8))]
    
    alpha, beta = gamma_parameters(perc_20, 0.2, perc_80, 0.8) # from preceding blog post
    
    def f(x0):
        a, loc, scale = x0
        return np.dot(y_cdf, ss.gamma(a, loc, scale).cdf(x))
    
    res = minimize(f, [alpha,0,beta])
    plt.plot(x,y, label = 'original distribution')
    plt.plot(x,ss.gamma(*params).pdf(x), label = 'fitted distribution')
    plt.legend()

    plt.show()
```

[image: empirical distribution + fitted one]

The fitted parameters appears to give a flat distribution.

### What I ended up so far:

I've finally ended up to generate synthetic data to fit distribution on it

```py
    import scipy.stats as ss
    import numpy as np
        
    x = np.linspace(1000,5500)
    y = get_implied_pdf()

    y_cdf = np.cumsum(y)
    
    @np.vectorize
    def gen_data(u):
        return x[np.argmin(np.abs(y_cdf - u ))]
    
    data = gen_data(ss.uniform().rvs(10000))
    
    params = ss.gamma.fit(data)
    plt.plot(x,y, label = 'original distribution')
    plt.plot(x,ss.gamma(*params).pdf(x), label = 'fitted distribution')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

[image: empirical distribution and better fit]

So, at the end, I've the parameters but it seems hackish and slow.
Any ways / methods to fit `ss.gamma` directly on the pdf ?
or any way to find better `init_guess` for solver ?

Thanks

edit : detail in progression to solution

Comment: I don't see why the fitting/optimization approach wouldn't work when using reasonable start values. Just define a function which takes the gamma distribution parameters as input and returns the MSE relative to your target curve. Then minimize.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that but I didn't find a way to compute "reasonable start value". I've take loc = x[y.argmax()], scale = loc - x[np.argmin(np.abs(y - y.max()/2))] and alpha = 1 but it didn't work. curve_fit, whitout the need of x0, return "max iteration error"

Comment: You could start from the mean and variance of your distribution and get parameter guesses from there, using the known functions for mean and variance of the gamma dist. For example, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=gammadistribution%28alpha%3D20%2C+beta%3D200%29) I'm drawing the gamma pdf for alpha=20 and beta=200, which looks similar as your case. As a general caveat: In general, I wouldn't assume that all libraries/sources define the parameters in the same way. Beta in one case might be 1/beta in the other.

Comment: Why do you have three parameters loc, scale and alpha?

Comment: How do you compute  the mean and variance of a distribution when you have only pdf ?

Comment: It's the scipy signature ss.gamma(a, loc, scale). according to the doc scale = 1/beta https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html

Comment: @Loïc you compute the mean and variance when you have pdf from their definitions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Random_variables_with_density later in that article you can see a formula for the variance, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Uses_and_applications you can use the pdf to get the expected value and the second moment (expectation of `x^2`) and use these to calculate the variance. These can be calculated numerically from the `implied_pdf`.